# Auto activate html5 widget in an iBook

Tags: ios, ipad, ibooks, ibook-author

I am trying to give my iBook a more app like feel. To do this I need the HTML5 widget I have created to automatically activate once a page is opened so the user doesn't need to click on it.

Is this something that is possible in iBooks and iBooks Author?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible in iBooks and iBooks Author. You have to interact with the HTML widget before it activates, unfortunately. It's how iBooks is designed.

Answer (score 0):

iBooks author 2.2 has an option in the widget inspector labeled "plays automatically." Its tool tip suggests that it will automatically launch the widget when the page is displayed. Doesn't work for MY widget, but maybe for yours!

Comment: "plays automatically" works, test your widget in a browser and make sure there are no errors and call widget.notifyContentIsReady() as recommended in Apple's document https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204433